# Associative enveloping algebra for non Lie algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, lie-algebras

Is it possible for any algebra (for example commutative) to construct an associative enveloping algebra as we do for Lie algebras?

If so, can I get any reference?

Comment: There is an associative enveloping algebra for every non-associative algebra, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-associative_algebra#Enveloping_algebra), section 5.2.